# Limit line length in multiline textbox

Tags: c#, wpf

I need to limit the number of characters on a single line that a user can enter into a multiline textbox. I have a function that can do that for data typed in, but not for data cut and pasted in.

I've tried reading the textbox into an array, using substring, and copying back to the text string, but this code (posted) throws an exception.

```
private void LongLine_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        int lineCount = 
 ((System.Windows.Controls.TextBox)sender).LineCount;
        //string newText = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < lineCount; i++)
        {
            if 
    (((System.Windows.Controls.TextBox)sender).GetLineLength(i) > 20)
            {
                string textString = ((System.Windows.Controls.TextBox)sender).Text;
                string[] textArray = Regex.Split(textString, "\r\n");
                textString = "";
                for (int k =0; k < textArray.Length; k++)
                {
                    String textSubstring = textArray[k].Substring(0, 20);
                    textString += textSubstring;
                }
                ((System.Windows.Controls.TextBox)sender).Text = textString;
            }
        }
        e.Handled = true;
    }
```

Comment: What's the exception, and where does it occur?  You may consider adding some code like this up at the top: `var theTextbox = sender as System.Windows.Controls.TextBox; if (theTextbox == null) return;`  it would certainly make your code easier to read

Comment: This is never going to work that well. i am not sure a multline text box with this kind of live ability is going to be very satisfying, its just going to act in weird ways all the time with cursor position ect and live editing

Comment: Thanks, Michael. I may well be heading in the wrong direction. Max Length, of course, only applies to the entire textbox. Has anyone written a function or modified property that would apply MaxLength to each line in a multiline box? The text is bound, with update set to Property Change, if that helps.

Comment: You're fixing and updating the whole text content once per line that is over 20. That seems unnecessary, although not the source of the error imagine (although you haven't provided details of the error).

Comment: Your error is that you get a substring from lines that are not longer than 20 (due to processing all lines every time you find one with 20 chars or more). Also, it seems you are splitting on \r\n but not putting them back in - is that what you want - to remove all line returns? Except that would then exceed the 20 char per line rule and it will repeat until there are only 20 chars in the whole textbox :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does what you seem to be asking for:

It truncates the end of any line that is longer than 20 as you type and when you paste or otherwise change the text.

```
private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    const int MAX_LINE_LENGTH = 20;
    var textbox = sender as TextBox;
    var exceedsLength = false;
    // First test if we need to modify the text
    for (int i = 0; i < textbox.LineCount; i++)
    {
        if (textbox.GetLineLength(i) > MAX_LINE_LENGTH)
        {
            exceedsLength = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (exceedsLength)
    {
        // Split the text into lines
        string[] oldTextArray = textbox.Text.Split(new[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);
        var newTextLines = new List<string>(textbox.LineCount);
        for (int k = 0; k < oldTextArray.Length; k++)
        {
            // truncate each line
            newTextLines.Add(string.Concat(oldTextArray[k].Take(MAX_LINE_LENGTH)));
        }
        // Save the cursor position
        var cursorPos = textbox.SelectionStart;
        // To avoid the text change calling back into this event, detach the event while setting the Text property
        textbox.TextChanged -= TextBox_TextChanged;
        // Set the new text
        textbox.Text = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, newTextLines);
        textbox.TextChanged += TextBox_TextChanged;
        // Restore the cursor position
        textbox.SelectionStart = cursorPos;
        // if at the end of the line, the position will advance automatically to the next line, supress that
        if (textbox.SelectionStart != cursorPos)
        {
            textbox.SelectionStart = cursorPos - 1;
        }
    }
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

Comment: This not only solves my problem, Andrew, but I will study it for my further education in WPF/C#. Thanks very much, and for explaining my error in my earlier code.